# Best practice for receiving large messages on ServiceBus though Batch

Tags: c#, .net, batch-processing, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I am using **ReceiveBatch** API to process the messages(Batch Processing) from Azure Service Bus. In this I noticed following.

When message size increased number of messages received in a batch gets decreased.

**For examples**

1. When BatchSize =50, MessageSize = 20Kb and Prefetch Count = 50 ===> Number of messages received while Calling serviceBusClient.ReceiveBatch = **12 messages**
2. When BatchSize =50, MessageSize = 10Kb and Prefetch Count = 50 ===> Number of messages received while Calling serviceBusClient.ReceiveBatch = **22 messages**
3. When BatchSize =50, MessageSize = 5Kb and Prefetch Count = 50 ===> Number of messages received while Calling serviceBusClient.ReceiveBatch = **44messages**

In all above 3 scenarios, around 220 to 240 KB messages I can receive at a time. 
**So here what are the best practices to receive the more numbers of messages regardless of message size ? in batch processing(serviceBusClient.ReceiveBatch)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum size of the messages that can be processed in batch is 256 KB. The batch gets rejected if the size id greater then 256 KB.

Irrespective of single or batch processing, you can only send or receive the messages within 256 KB.

To make the size of the message deterministic, add the real message content to a blob storage and send the blob URL as the message body. Here, the size of all the messages will be same and very less.

Thus, you can determine the number of messages that can be processes per batch.

This can also be achieved using [Service Bus Plugins](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/servicebus/2017/07/13/azure-service-bus-plugins/).

Comment: ~Thanks. I read the same one from .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-quotas                                                             
 Maximum message size: 256 KB (Standard tier) / 1 MB (Premium tier). Is this you want to say?

Comment: Exactly, Size limit is applicable for batch processing as well.

Comment: Note: batching is tricky with ASB. Currently it doesn't have a solid way to achieve "safe" batching. That hopefully will change. As for claim-check pattern @Arunprabhu has referred to, this can be done today by using a specific plugin, [ServiceBus.AttachmentPlugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceBus.AttachmentPlugin). You'll be able to either offload all of the messages to Storage or conditionally decide which ones would be sent as-is vs offloaded.

Comment: Sean ~ I am not getting what do you mean by "safe" batching ?

Comment: What to do If I want to process message having size greater than 300Kb in (Standard Tier) and 1 MB in(Premium Tier)?